# Starscream websockets does not connect

Tags: node.js, swift, sockets, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect to my AWS EC2 linux instance using starscream web sockets in swift, but every time I run my code, the socket does not connect.

This is the code I use to setup and connect the socket:

```
var socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "ws://My-ec2-instance:8085")!, protocols: ["test"])

func connect() {
    socket.disableSSLCertValidation = true
    socket.delegate = self as WebSocketDelegate
    socket.connect()
}
```

I have these two delegate methods:

```
func websocketDidConnect(socket: WebSocket) {
    print("websocket is connected")
}

func websocketDidDisconnect(socket: WebSocket, error: NSError?) {
    print("websocket is disconnected: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
}
```

But whenever I execute the `connect()` function, the `websocketDidDisconnect` method gets called and this is printed in the console: `websocket is disconnected: nil`

Comment: did you add `app transport security` in your plist file, you need to allow access to this specific endpoint

Comment: enable the port in security group first of ec2

Comment: Already did both of these things

Comment: @Mr.Man have you found any solution I am struggling in this

Comment: Yeah, I got it to work. What questions do you have?

Comment: @Mr.Man, How did you debug this? what was the reason for this?

Comment: @santhosh This was a while ago so I don't remember exactly what I did. But if I'm not mistaken, it was a problem that had to be fixed on AWS rather than in Xcode.

Comment: I have verified error at my side. The problem is that the server was not configured to support HTTP.